# no match for call to ‘(std::vector<std::vector<int> >) (int, std::vector<int>)’

Tags: c++

My error:

```
Matrix.cpp:13:27: error: no match for call to ‘(std::vector<std::vector<int> >) (int, std::vector<int>)’
     M(3, vector<int>(3, 0));
```

part of my Matrix.h file

```
vector<vector<int> > M;
```

part of my Matrix.cpp file

```
Matrix::Matrix() {
M(3, vector<int>(3, 0));
}
```

I'm not too sure if I have to write vector< vector< int > > in front of M for my .cpp file. The overall goal of this constructor is to create a 3x3 matrix via a 2D vector and assign all the elements within the matrix to be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong syntax, if you want to init M in the initializer list, it should be:

```
Matrix::Matrix() : M(3, vector<int>(3, 0)) // <---
{}
```

Comment: thanks for the response but how come you don't put M inside the curly braces?

Comment: data members are created before code in {} is performed, so M can be constructed by default ctor of vector, which doesn't take any params, or you can invoke `vector(int elem,T elem)` ctor in initializer list. In {} you can modify M by assignment operations.

Comment: @Yao Note that you can also write `M.resize(3, vector<int>(3, 0));` in the constructor body, but the solution in this answer is a better one. Learn about [member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to find out more details.